# Insecure Login Facebook API

Tags: python, django, facebook, api

I want to create Facebook authorization in my django site. I find many libraries that can do this. I am using [social_django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html) (This is link for tutorial, not for docs). I am doing all written in tutorial, but I get error in **facebook API**, when I redirected in it. I am using ngrok so instead`localhost` i use `https` connection, but when I try authorize i get this error:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

I can understand what is wrong. One place when i find not https is redirect_url in get parameter, instead of https `social_django` use http, I don`t know why.

The question is how i can test my application with facebook api local?

Comment: Did you load the page from where you _trigger_ the login flow via HTTPS already?

Comment: @CBroe, I don't fully understand about what you ask, I run `manage.py runserver` run ngrok, and now I try to login with facebook via `https://8de8c91b.ngrok.io/login/` this url in my site

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant, whether you are calling the whole thing via `https://` in your browser from the very start. You _need_ to get the `redirect_url` parameter to contains an HTTPS URL as well, that why I’m asking - many such frameworks/libraries construct this value based on the current URL, so if you called this via HTTP only, that could explain the value. But if that’s not it, then it is probably rather an issue of configuration - some “app base URL” or similar setting somewhere  maybe.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, I am think so, I am searching throw documentation some settings configuration that can help me